# Print tree traversal path in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, nodes, depth-first-search

I have an n-ary tree. I want to print every node in a particular path, starting from the root node, and ending when the node possesses a certain quality.

I’ve been using depth-first search. One by one, I add nodes to a list with the intention of printing it.

When I encounter a childfree node and circle back to the previous node with more than one child, I want to delete the nodes that make up the previous branch.

Unfortunately, I was not successful. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your code. It is a bit hard to see what you did wrong without it.